# Storing objects using core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm brand new to core data, and I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to store an object (a recent address). Here is my code:

```
NSError *error;
recentSearch = [[RecentSearch alloc] init];
[recentSearch setName:[searchTextField text]];
[recentSearch setDate:[NSDate date]];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [recentSearch managedObjectContext];

if(![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Not saved. Error: %@",[error description]);
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Saved");
}
```

I don't think this is working though. Is there anything wrong with this code? recentSearch is an `NSManagedObject`. My code prints `Not saved. Error: (null)`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by giving this a quick glance; you need to initialize the NSManagedObject using NSManagedObject's initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:, thereby actually inserting it into the context. I suggest you take a look at [The NSManagedObject class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) and [Apple's Core Data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). I've found both extremely helpful.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks! I knew I was missing one line. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Where did you obtain the context from?

You create a NSManagedObject the non standard way.

Normally you would ask the CoreData to get a NSManagedObject with an NSEntityDescription.
You can do this by using the NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext: shortcut

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecentSearch" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
```

where self.moc is your NSManagedObject context created on application initialization. 
A piece of sample code is included when you start a project with CoreData support in your app delegate.

Basically this asks your CoreData model (NSManagedObjectModel) for an entity defined there.
The above is used for querying something in CoreData.

To insert a new object into the CoreData storage you would use the shortcut

```
NSManagedObject *myManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RecentSearch" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
```

Now there exists a new managed object in your memory. That object can be filled with data and will be written to the underlying persistent storage when you call [self.moc save:&error];

Hope this helps a little bit.